# Query data inside embedded array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I've an data in a collection as below.

```
{
"date":"01-01-2014",
"details": [ 
    {"name":"abc", 
     "address":{
         "city":"abc" , "state":"abc"
               },
    {"name":"xyz", 
     "address":{
          "city":"xyz" , "state":"xyz"
               }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want all records having city as "abc" . I am using Java.

I tried below queries and the output is null.

```
Query searchQuery = new Query();
searchQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("details.address.$.city").is("abc"));
```

and

```
searchQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("details.address.city").is("abc"));
```

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What is wrong with your second form? Because that should work. Are you expecting the `details` array to **only** contain the items with `city` matching "abc"?

Comment: Sorry...this was working... I was passing the value wrong.